# Getting error "All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification" but not using Firebase in project

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-realtime-database, dependencies

I've been getting this error and have tried all the steps to fix I've found online. The error says a gms/firebase library is the wrong version but there are no firebase dependancies in the app.

**The error:**

"All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 16.0.1, 16.0.0. Examples include `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0`"

The dependency `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0` is not in my dependencies and yet it still says it's the wrong version compared with the play-services-maps.
I've tried changing play-services-maps to 16.0.1 but that version doesn't exist. I've also tried adding `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.0'` to the file, but it gives the same error.

**My Build.gradle (App)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nameomitted"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**My Build.gradle (project)**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those are examples, not necessarily what's in your project. However, you also have mismatched support dependencies, an outdated Gradle version, and unmatched compile/target versions that also don't match any of your support versions. In short, your dependencies are a mess. Fix the versioning and the errors will go away.

Comment: Alright, I'll try and fix that now. Thanks.